# Solve University Courses Constraint satisfaction problem with Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that contains some university courses.

- Each course has `pre-requisites` and `co-requisites` where `pre-requisites` are the courses that should be passed **before** being able to register a specific course.
- `Co-requisites` are the courses that should be passed **before** taking the course, or courses that can be registered **with** the course that we are looking forward to registering **at the same semester**.

For example, this is a part of my dataframe.

| course_name | pre_requisites | co_requisites |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Calculus A |  |  |
| Calculus B | Calculus A |  |
| Linear Algebra |  |  |
| Calculus C | [Calculus B, Linear Algebra] |  |
| Differential Equations | Linear Algebra | Calculus C |
| Computer Programming | [Calculus A, Linear Algebra] |  |
| Physics A |  | Calculus A |
| Physics A Lab |  | Physics A |
| Physics B | Physics A |  |
| Physics B Lab | Physics A Lab | Physics B |
| Electrical Circuits | Physics B | Differential Equations |
| Electrical Circuits Lab | Physics B Lab | Electrical Circuits |
| Digital Logic | [Computer Programming, Electrical Circuits, Electrical Circuits Lab] |  |
| Digital Logic Lab |  | Digital Logic |

I covered all of the cases.

- There are courses without `pre-requisites` nor `co-requisites` like `Calculus A`.
- Also, there are courses with `co-requisites` but without `pre-requisites` like `Digital Logic Lab`.
- Also, there are courses which are a chain of `co-requisites` like `Electrical Circuits Lab` which requires you to pass `Electrical Circuits` or register it at the same semester.

  - So, if you only passed `Physics B`, `Physics B Lab`, `Calculus B` and `Linear Algebra`, and you want to register `Electrical Circuits Lab`, then you need to register `Calculus C`, `Differential Equations` and `Electrical Circuits` at the same semester.
- Finally, for simplicity, a course have zero or one `co-requisite`(s) only.

I need a solution that I can give an input which is the passed courses, and I get an output which is the courses that can be registered.

Here is a part of my courses data source (`courses.csv`):

```
course_name,pre_requisites,co_requisite
Calculus-A,,
Calculus-B,Calculus-A,
Linear-Algebra,,
Calculus-C,Calculus-B_Linear-Algebra,
Differential-Equations,Linear-Algebra,Calculus-C
Computer-Programming,Calculus-A_Linear-Algebra,
Physics-A,,Calculus-A
Physics-A-Lab,,Physics-A
Physics-B,Physics-A,
Physics-B-Lab,Physics-A-Lab,Physics-B
Electrical-Circuits,Physics-B,Differential-Equations
Electrical-Circuits-Lab,Physics-B-Lab,Electrical-Circuits
Digital-Logic,Computer-Programming_Electrical-Circuits_Electrical-Circuits-Lab,
Digital-Logic-Lab,,Digital-Logic
```

Here is a part of my python code:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('courses.csv', dtype=str)
df.fillna('', inplace=True)

df['finished'] = False

finished_courses = ['Calculus-A', 'Calculus-B', 'Linear-Algebra', 'Physics-A', 'Physics-A-Lab', 'Physics-B',
                    'Physics-B-Lab']

for finished_course in finished_courses:
    df.loc[df['course_name'] == finished_course, 'finished'] = True

df['pre_requisites'] = df['pre_requisites'].apply(lambda pre_requisites: pre_requisites.split('_'))

courses_without_pre_requisites = df[df['pre_requisites'].apply(lambda pre_requisites: pre_requisites == [''])]
courses_without_pre_requisites_without_co_requisites = courses_without_pre_requisites[
    courses_without_pre_requisites['co_requisite'].apply(lambda co_requisites: co_requisites == '')]
courses_without_pre_requisites_with_co_requisites = courses_without_pre_requisites[
    courses_without_pre_requisites['co_requisite'].apply(lambda co_requisites: co_requisites != '')]
courses_with_pre_requisites = df[df['pre_requisites'].apply(lambda pre_requisites: pre_requisites != [''])]
courses_with_pre_requisites_with_co_requisites = courses_with_pre_requisites[
    courses_with_pre_requisites['co_requisite'].apply(lambda co_requisites: co_requisites != '')]
courses_with_pre_requisites_without_co_requisites = courses_with_pre_requisites[
    courses_with_pre_requisites['co_requisite'].apply(lambda co_requisites: co_requisites == '')]
courses_with_finished_pre_requisites = courses_with_pre_requisites_without_co_requisites[
    courses_with_pre_requisites_without_co_requisites['pre_requisites'].apply(
        lambda pre_requisite: set(pre_requisite).issubset(set(df[df['finished']]['course_name'])))]

courses_to_be_registered = pd.concat(
    [courses_without_pre_requisites_without_co_requisites, courses_with_finished_pre_requisites])
courses_to_be_registered = courses_to_be_registered[~(courses_to_be_registered['finished'])]

print('Courses to be registered:')
print(courses_to_be_registered['course_name'])
```

Here is the output:

```bash
Courses to be registered:
Calculus-C
Computer-Programming
```

Here is the desired output:

```bash
Calculus-C
Differential-Equations
Computer-Programming
Electrical-Circuits
Electrical-Circuits-Lab
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you can use recursion for the task:

```py
def check_apply(course):
    def _can_be_applied(c):
        if not c["pre_requisites"] and not c["co_requisite"]:
            return True
        elif not c["pre_requisites"] and c["co_requisite"]:
            return _can_be_applied(df.loc[c["co_requisite"]])
        else:
            return all(v in finished_courses for v in c["pre_requisites"])

    return _can_be_applied(course)


# load the CSV, change NaNs to empty lists and ""
df = pd.read_csv("your_data.csv")
df["pre_requisites"] = df["pre_requisites"].apply(
    lambda x: x.split("_") if pd.notna(x) else []
)
df["co_requisite"] = df["co_requisite"].fillna("")


finished_courses = {
    "Calculus-A",
    "Calculus-B",
    "Linear-Algebra",
    "Physics-A",
    "Physics-A-Lab",
    "Physics-B",
    "Physics-B-Lab",
}

mask = ~df["course_name"].isin(finished_courses).values
df = df.set_index("course_name")

df.loc[mask, "can_apply"] = df[mask].apply(check_apply, axis=1)
print(df)
```

Creates `can_apply` column where `True` means the courses user can apply:

```
                                                                               pre_requisites            co_requisite can_apply
course_name                                                                                                                    
Calculus-A                                                                                 []                               NaN
Calculus-B                                                                       [Calculus-A]                               NaN
Linear-Algebra                                                                             []                               NaN
Calculus-C                                                       [Calculus-B, Linear-Algebra]                              True
Differential-Equations                                                       [Linear-Algebra]              Calculus-C      True
Computer-Programming                                             [Calculus-A, Linear-Algebra]                              True
Physics-A                                                                                  []              Calculus-A       NaN
Physics-A-Lab                                                                              []               Physics-A       NaN
Physics-B                                                                         [Physics-A]                               NaN
Physics-B-Lab                                                                 [Physics-A-Lab]               Physics-B       NaN
Electrical-Circuits                                                               [Physics-B]  Differential-Equations      True
Electrical-Circuits-Lab                                                       [Physics-B-Lab]     Electrical-Circuits      True
Digital-Logic            [Computer-Programming, Electrical-Circuits, Electrical-Circuits-Lab]                             False
Digital-Logic-Lab                                                                          []           Digital-Logic     False
```

Comment: Your code solved my problem, thank you. But I have a question, why does some values of `can_apply` are NaN? EDIT: I got it, it is because they are already finished. I will use `fillna` to give them a `False` value.